# How can LoRa transmit without interference even though SigFox also transmits on the same frequency?

Tags: frequency, electromagnetism, lora

LoRa and Sigfox both transmit over 868MHz ISM band. What solution does LoRa offer so that the contact continues to function without interference (Although Sigfox also transmits on the same frequency)? How can LoRa transmit without interference even though SigFox also transmits on the same frequency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 868MHz ISM band has Power limit, spectral density, Listen before talk and duty cycle rules (1% Transmit time) That all compliant products must adhere to.
This makes everyone a good neighbor, and allows shared usage of the spectrum.